# Result interpretation for Regression With ARIMA Errors

Tags: time-series, arima

I am new to time-series analysis.

I am struggling to interpret the result I got from auto.arima().

I've read the highly-recommended blog https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/.
I also read a similar question on [ARIMAX vs. Regression With ARIMA Errors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/418259/arimax-vs-regression-with-arima-errors) but I still got a few more questions.

My code (I was using  auto.arima() to analyze daily ridership data in Boston and I did not do any data manipulation beforehand, like taking log or standard scaling on variables) :

```
weather_indicators =  df_2019[['Boston Temperature_mean','Boston Precipitation Total','Boston Evapotranspiration','Boston Sunshine Duration','Boston Relative Humidity_mean']]
model2 = pm.auto_arima(df_2019['Total_Daily'], suppress_warnings=True,exogenous = weather_indicators, seasonal=True, m=7)
```

I used python here but my understanding is that the pmdarima should be very similar to  auto.arima() in R.

And I got a result looks like this:
[image]

The above result is pretty rough but still I would like to know:

**1. Interpretation on coefficients**

The coefficients for the exogenous variables (especially the first 3 weather variables) are much larger than coefficients for AR and MA.
Does that mean the weather is much more statistically significant to the daily ridership number than the time-series factors are? or is it because the auto_arima() is a Regression with ARMA errors, which renders the coefficient for exogenous variables always being much larger than those for AR,MA?

**2. ARIMAX vs  multiple linear regression**

My focus was on  studying the effect of the exogenous variables.
If time-series factor (coefficients for AR and MA) are not that statistically significant(very low in this case), maybe a multiple linear regression (between daily ridership and different weather variables) would be more appropriate? Or this SARIMAX result is good enough?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Interpretation on coefficients:** First of all, $AR(p)$ and $MA(q)$ terms are bounded between $(-1,1)$ or else the process is not stationary. Second, you judge whether a coefficient is statistically significant based on the relevant $t-test$. For example your third exogenous variable, while large on absolute terms, also has large standard error and cannot be considered statistically significant at the $1\%$ confidence level (i.e. there is a chance $>1\%$ that this coefficient is actually $0$). Third, if your exogenous variables are of different scale it is reasonable to have large discrepancies in absolute terms in the coefficients. So the answer is that I cannot judge which coefficient is more important at this stage; this would probably require applying a method such forward or backward selection in order to assess the impact of each predictor separately.
2. **ARIMAX vs multiple linear regression**: Good enough is relevant. There are several ways of evaluating a model's performance. Some of them are based on in-sample diagnostics: [$R^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination), [residual diagnostics](https://otexts.com/fpp2/residuals.html) and [Akaike information criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) among others. In fact I believe that `auto.arima()` uses AIC as a default for model selection. If forecasting is your goal, you should probably evaluate based on the [forecast accuracy](https://otexts.com/fpp2/accuracy.html) on a hold-out set. I would suggest checking the residual diagnostics to get a first assessment of the quality of your model. If your residuals are $i.i.d.$ it would indicate a good fit.