# SARIMAX exogenous coefs change with order of p and q

Tags: statsmodels

SARIMAX Statsmodels fits a regression with ARMA errors. So the model is:

yt=βxt+ut

ut=μ+ηt−1+ζt

Since p and q orders only affect the second equation, why do I get different results (coefs) of the exogenous variables? What am i missing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that while there are two separate equations, the fitting is not done in two separate steps. (Your question sounds like you are assuming this, which is quite understandable, but [`statsmodels.sarimax`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html) does not work this way.) Rather, there is a single estimation step in which *all* the parameters are estimated - those for the regression *and* those for the SARIMA process on the residuals. And of course, if the SARIMA model order changes, then all parameters can (and usually will) change: those of the SARIMA error process *and* those of the regression on predictors.

Here is an earlier thread that covers regression with ARIMA errors (not SARIMA, but that doesn't make a difference here), in the R `forecast` package (which the various ARIMA functionalities in Python are patterned on, because it's the gold standard), by the author of the `forecast` package for R himself: [ARIMAX vs. Regression With ARIMA Errors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/418340/1352).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was assuming a two steps fitting.